# Python - How to set multiple attributes of an object at once?

Tags: javascript, python

I have an object i need to set multiple attributes, in JavaScript, you can do so with the "with" statement, example:

```
with(anObjectPreferences){
    range = fastRange.all;
    compatibility = compatibility.fastlane;
    guides = false;
    layers = false;
    reader = false;
    thumbnails = false;
}
```

How can I do the same in Python? For now I'm doing this like so but it's not efficient isn't it?

```
anObjectPreferences.range = fastRange.all
anObjectPreferences.compatibility = compatibility.fastlane
anObjectPreferences.guides = false
anObjectPreferences.layers = false
anObjectPreferences.reader = false
anObjectPreferences.thumbnails = false
```

Comment: Why do you think it's "not efficient"? Also, `with` in Javascript is [highly discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Comment: `with` is massively unrecommended in JS, and was removed from ECMAScript in version 5. See for example [this old blog post](https://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/).

Comment: You could use `vars(anObjectPreferences).update({...})`, but that's rather hacky. Give your object a dedicated method to update multiple attributes instead.

Comment: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesn-t-python-have-a-with-statement-like-some-other-languages.htm

Comment: @MartijnPieters `vars` would seem a good option (better than using a dunder `__dict__`) . You should add it as an answer in the dupe...

Comment: (or reopen this and answer here)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: except that bypasses any data descriptors (such as `property` objects) and `__setattr__` hooks. That's why it is hacky.

Comment: Thanks everyone!